# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin e^{-x}\cos e^{-x} \ln e^{-x}\;dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate the following integral?
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin e^{-x}\cos e^{-x} \ln e^{-x}\;dx$$

Comment: @CameronWilliams you still have that $\ln e^{-x}$ term. Using IBP doesn't make it clean either.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Making the variable change wouldn't be advised. Then you would have $\ln u$

Comment: @VarunIyer Oh doh. You're right.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, this gives a cosine integral so it seems like there is a typo of some sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering $$I=\int e^{-x}\sin (e^{-x})\cos( e^{-x}) \ln (e^{-x})\;dx$$the most natural change of variable seems to be $e^{-x}=t$. So $$I=-\int\log (t) \sin (t) \cos (t)\;dt=-\frac 12\int\log (t) \sin (2t) \;dt$$ Integrating by parts once to remove the logarithm then leads to $$I=\frac{1}{4} \log (t) \cos (2 t)-\frac{\text{Ci}(2 t)}{4}$$ and to the integral the result is $$\frac{1}{4} (\text{Ci}(2)-\gamma -\log (2))$$

Comment: @Integrator. It is amazing to notice that, very often, this happens to you and I : same answer, same time ! Cheers. Your turn now.

Answer (score 1):

First substituting $z=e^{-x}$ and then integrating by parts, this integral may evaluated in terms of the cosine integral function, $\operatorname{Ci}{(x)}$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin{\left(e^{-x}\right)}\cos{\left(e^{-x}\right)}\ln{\left(e^{-x}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sin{(z)}\cos{(z)}\ln{(z)}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\left[\sin^2{(z)}\ln{(z)}\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\sin{(z)}\left(\frac{\sin{(z)}}{z}+\cos{(z)}\ln{(z)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^2{(z)}}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z-\int_{0}^{1}\sin{(z)}\cos{(z)}\ln{(z)}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^2{(z)}}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z-\mathcal{I}\\
\implies 2\mathcal{I}&=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^2{(z)}}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
\implies \mathcal{I}&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^2{(z)}}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=-\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\cos{(2z)}}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=-\frac14\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1-\cos{(t)}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\frac14\operatorname{Cin}{(2)}\\
&=-\frac14\left(\gamma+\ln{(2)}-\operatorname{Ci}{(2)}\right).\\
\end{align}$$

---

**Note on Definitions:**

A couple of different definitions of the [cosine integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral), $\operatorname{Ci}{(x)}$, include either,

$$\operatorname{Ci}{(x)}:=-\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$

or,

$$\operatorname{Ci}{(x)}:=\gamma+\ln{(x)}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos{t}-1}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

For convenience we may also define the related auxiliary function, $\operatorname{Cin}{(x)}$,

$$\operatorname{Cin}{(x)}:=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1-\cos{t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$

implying the relation,

$$\operatorname{Cin}{(x)}=\gamma+\ln{(x)}-\operatorname{Ci}{(x)}.$$

Comment: $\operatorname{Ci}, \operatorname{Cin}$... what kind of functions are these?

Comment: @Joe The function Ci is the cosine integral function. I've updated my response to include a note on the definitions. The link goes to the associated Wikipedia article.